# Java EnumSet - Add and check if set contains a flag

Tags: java, enumset

I am trying to understand how to properly use EnumSet for an equivalent to C#'s Flags.  Here is my implementation and methods that use this.  As you can see, checking if a flag exists is not working properly.  Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

I have the following Enum with an EnumSet:

```
public enum ExcelRangeBordersFlag {
    BORDER_LEFT,
    BORDER_BOTTOM,
    BORDER_TOP,
    BORDER_RIGHT;

    public static final EnumSet<ExcelRangeBordersFlag> SELECTED_BORDERS = EnumSet.noneOf(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.class);
}
```

(Is this implemented correctly?)

I now want to be able to do things like add to the set, and check to see if the set contains a value.  But, this isn't working:

```
private static ExcelRangeBordersFlag getBordersFlag(boolean bottom, boolean top, boolean left, boolean right){
        ExcelRangeBordersFlag results =  null; 

        if (bottom){
            results.SELECTED_BORDERS.add(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_BOTTOM);
        }

        if (top){
            results.SELECTED_BORDERS.add(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_TOP);
        }

        if (left){
            results.SELECTED_BORDERS.add(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_LEFT);
        }

        if (right){
            results.SELECTED_BORDERS.add(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_RIGHT);
        }

        System.out.println(results);

        return results;
    }


private static void MergeAndWriteToCell(Sheet sh, int sRow, int eRow, int sCell, int eCell, ExcelRangeBordersFlag borders , String text){
        CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(sRow, eRow, sCell, eCell);
        sh.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
        Row row = sh.getRow(sRow);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(sCell);
        cell.setCellValue(text);

        if (borders.SELECTED_BORDERS.contains(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_BOTTOM)){
            RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, cellRangeAddress, sh, wb);
            System.out.println("Contains bottom.");
        }

        if (borders.SELECTED_BORDERS.contains(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_LEFT)){
            RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, cellRangeAddress, sh, wb);
            System.out.println("Contains left.");
        }

        if (borders.SELECTED_BORDERS.contains(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_TOP)){
            RegionUtil.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, cellRangeAddress, sh, wb);
            System.out.println("Contains top.");
        }

        if (borders.SELECTED_BORDERS.contains(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_RIGHT)){
            RegionUtil.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, cellRangeAddress, sh, wb);
            System.out.println("Contains right.");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
```

The last method shows that all ExcelRangeBorder types are contained, even when I do the following:

```
borders = getBordersFlag(false, false, false, false);
        MergeAndWriteToCell(sh, 4,4,1,3, borders, "Percent of Original List Price Received*");
```

**Output:**

```
null
Contains bottom.
Contains left.
Contains top.
Contains right.
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: getBordersFlag should give me back the enum with a proper EnumSet.  The MergeAndWriteToCell should be able to see if the set contains any one of the border values.

Comment: That isn't a question

Comment: The example shows that this isn't working.  The question is, how do I make it work?

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging your code?

Comment: In your `getBordersFlag` method what is the purpose of `ExcelRangeBordersFlag results =  null;`? Your code `results.SELECTED_BORDERS.add(...)` is same as `ExcelRangeBordersFlag.SELECTED_BORDERS.add(...)` since `SELECTED_BORDERS` is static field of `ExcelRangeBordersFlag` class (enum).

Comment: Also could you post [minimal but **full** code example which will let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org) (so we could simply copy-paste it). Your current code contains things like `CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM` which are not part of your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root of your problem is that `SELECTED_BORDERS` should *not* be a static field in `ExcelRangeBordersFlag`, but rather, should be the thing you pass around.  For example, it looks like you should write

```
private static Set<ExcelRangeBordersFlag> getBordersFlag(
      boolean bottom, boolean top, boolean left, boolean right){
    ExcelRangeBordersFlag results = EnumSet.noneOf(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.class); 

    if (bottom){
        results.add(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_BOTTOM);
    }

    if (top){
        results.add(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_TOP);
    }

    if (left){
        results.add(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_LEFT);
    }

    if (right){
        results.add(ExcelRangeBordersFlag.BORDER_RIGHT);
    }

    System.out.println(results);

    return results;
}
```

It looks ike you're trying to pass around an `ExcelRangeBordersFlag` as if it were a set of the flag values, but that's not how it works.  An `ExcelRangeBordersFlag` is a value like `BORDER_BOTTOM` or `BORDER_LEFT`.  You should be passing around a `Set` of them.

Comment: And probably rename the enum to alleviate confusion.